# Electron webview preload only file:// protocol is supported when using create-react-app base

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

Electron V3.0.5

Hello, I have a project using Electron and create-react-app and I can't get my project to find the preload script.

Here's the webview tag:

```
<webview preload={`./Injects/preload.js`} />
```

When I use the tag as shown, the console tells me that I must use `file:` protocol. So I tried going with:

```
<webview preload={`file://${__dirname}/Injects/preload.js`} />
```

but of course that brings me to the path of the .asar packed file which doesn't have the Injects/preload.js in it.

I also tried putting my inject script in my public folder and using

```
<webview preload={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Injects/preload.js`} />
```

and

```
<webview preload={`file://${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Injects/preload.js`} />
```

however I just get the same errors, and process.env.PUBLIC_URL returned "" anyway.

Any help would be much appreciated, I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I created a __static variable based off of __dirname which changed location depending on production or development builds.

Answer (score 1):

```
let path = `file:${require('path').resolve(__static, './preload.js')}`
```

I place the `preload.js` in the `static` folder in my electron project, and it worked for me